# Make a local copy of android project with different name - Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

After reading some posts and googled a while, I did the following but with some values changed to red colour which make me worry.

In MacOs, Copy/paste and rename. open the newly pasted project > refresh > select the newly named folder.
Right click to select the “app” under the Project side tab. right click > Refactor > Rename. Did it magic then.

I still find the old name in:
module `build.gradle` and `defaultConfig.applicationId` and `android:label “@string/app_name”.`

If I change the name in manifest-package, then the `android:name “.MyGlobal”` turns red along with `application.activity.android:label value`

I tried for no avail to manually edit the app's `build.gradle` and Manifest then run `gradle sync`, but that did not clear the red colour of the values stated above.
Any suggestions on how to properly change the project name so that I can play around with the new copy and leave the old one intact in case I need it later?

Comment: What did you change the package name from/to?

Comment: "app" to "thirtyfive"

Answer (score 0):

If you change the package name from "com.mypackage.app" to "com.mypackage.thirtyfive", then you also need to either:

1. refactor all your java/kotlin package names from "com.mypackage.app" -> "com.mypackage.thirtyfive" OR
2. replace `android:name=".MainActivity"` in the manifest to `android:name="com.mypackage.app.MainActivity"`

because when you use the short notation `android:name=".MainActivity"` in the  manifest, Android just prepends your package name to ".MainActivity" and it cannot find the source code.